# Como percorrer um os filhos e uma div com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, loop, dom

Preciso de uma função que percorra o #paicasas e deixe o background de todos os filhos "casa1,casa2...".

Tentei fazer isso mas sei que está longe de dar certo.

```
        function apagar(){
            for(var i in document.getElementById('paicasas')){
                document.getElementById('paicasas')[i].style.backgroundColor = "#FFF";
            }
        }
```

HTML

```
<div id="paicasas">
    <div id="casa1" onclick="mudarbg(this)"></div>
    <div id="casa2" onclick="mudarbg(this)"></div> 
    <div id="casa3" onclick="mudarbg(this)"></div> 
    </br>
    <div id="casa4" onclick="mudarbg(this)"></div> 
    <div id="casa5" onclick="mudarbg(this)"></div> 
    <div id="casa6" onclick="mudarbg(this)"></div> 
    </br>
    <div id="casa7" onclick="mudarbg(this)"></div> 
    <div id="casa8" onclick="mudarbg(this)"></div> 
    <div id="casa9" onclick="mudarbg(this)"></div> 
    <button type="button" onclick="apagar()">Novo</button>
</div>
```

Aproveitando, eu preciso muito de algum material que explique sobre DOM.

Comment: Sobre o material de DOM, por ser um assunto levemente diferente, é necessário abrir uma nova pergunta, ok? :)

Comment: O que você esperava que `for(var i in document.getElementById('paicasas'))` fosse fazer? Em geral, não é recomendado usar "for .. in" para acessar arrays (ou *array-likes*), de modo que mesmo que os filhos daquele elemento estivessem em índices a forma mais correta de iterar sobre eles seria usando um "for" comum mesmo.

Comment: E onde é recomendado usar for in?

Answer (score 3):

Estava quase certo; você só esqueceu de percorrer o array de filhos, ao invés dos atributos do elemento.

Adicionalmente, para pegar apenas as DIV's, basta verificar o valor do `tagName` de cada filho.

Veja o script final abaixo:

```
var pai = document.getElementById("paicasas");
for(var i = 0; i < pai.children.length; i++){
    if(pai.children[i].tagName == "DIV") pai.children[i].style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
}
```

Apenas para fins didáticos, o que você estava fazendo anteriormente era varrer cada atributo do objeto pai. Observe o que o console imprime:

```
for(var i in document.getElementById("paicasas")) console.log(i);
/*
  align
  onautocompleteerror
  onautocomplete
  onwaiting
  onvolumechange
  ontoggle
  ontimeupdate
  onsuspend
  ...
  children
  ...
*/
```

Comment: Um objeto comporta arrays? ñ sabia.

Comment: O que mudaria se o elemento pai fosse um <form>?

Comment: Um objeto é formato por pares de chave-valor; `children`, por exemplo, é uma chave, cujo valor é o *array* de objetos filhos; este array específico pode ser acessado através das sintaxes `elPai.children` ou `elPai["children"]`. Portanto, sim, um objeto pode conter não apenas um, mas **vários** arrays, bem como qualquer outro tipo de dados dentro dele :D

Comment: A tag, especificamente, não muda nada. `<div>`, `<form>`, `<table>`, etc, sendo um elemento HTML, ela é representada no JavaScript como um nó DOM; sendo um nó DOM, ela possui o atributo `children`, que consiste neste array de ponteiros para os elementos filhos :) Vale lembrar que nós-filhos *textuais* não são encontrados no array `children`, mas sim no `childNodes`.

Comment: Rui. Muito obrigado pelas explicações. Só me diz porque não é possível acessar o elemento filho do DOM através do getById a naos ser q seja um <form>! Por exemplo, errado: document.getElementById('divpai')divfilho.style.backgroundColor != "#FFF"; Certo:document.getElementById('form')input.style.backgroundColor != "#FFF".

Comment: Preparei um pequeno teste comentado para você :) http://jsfiddle.net/ruipimentel/k6wjm2dq/

| É preciso ativar o console do navegador para ver o resultado!

Answer (score 2):

Tenta assim

```
document.getElementById('paicasas').children[i].style.backgroundColor = "#FFF";
```

Answer (score 1):

Quando faz `for(var i in document.getElementById('paicasas')){` vai estar a percorrer todoas as propriedades desse objeto e não os elementos que são seus descendentes.

Sugiro usar assim:

```js
function mudarbg(el) {
    el.style.backgroundColor = "#F0F";
}

function apagar() {
    var divs = document.querySelectorAll('#paicasas > [id^=casa]');
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        divs[i].style.backgroundColor = "#FFF";
    }
}
```

```css
#paicasas > div {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 1px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="paicasas">
    <div id="casa1" onclick="mudarbg(this)"></div>
    <div id="casa2" onclick="mudarbg(this)"></div>
    <div id="casa3" onclick="mudarbg(this)"></div>
    <br/>
    <div id="casa4" onclick="mudarbg(this)"></div>
    <div id="casa5" onclick="mudarbg(this)"></div>
    <div id="casa6" onclick="mudarbg(this)"></div>
    <br/>
    <div id="casa7" onclick="mudarbg(this)"></div>
    <div id="casa8" onclick="mudarbg(this)"></div>
    <div id="casa9" onclick="mudarbg(this)"></div>
    <button type="button" onclick="apagar()">Novo</button>
</div>
```

`[id^=casa]` vai selecionar elementos cuja ID comece por `casa`.